# Managing activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity, let's say CategoriesActivity. This activity extends ListActivity with a custom adapter to set a custom layout for listview items. This activity shows a screen with a list of categories from where user can select a single category. Once selected, category identifier is returned to the caller activity.

I reuse this activity, I mean, this activity is called from two different points in my application:

1. From another activity, let's say, ItemActivity.
2. From the main app activity, let's say, MainActivity.

**In first scenario**, ItemActivity calls CategoryActivity using startActivityForResult. Once result returned, the corresponding title to the returned category identifier is shown in a ItemActivity's TextView widget (title is extracted from a database using the category id).

**In second scenario**, I need to call CategoryActivity from the MainActivity and stay in CategoryActivity until a valid category is selected. A valid category is that having products associated. To know if there are products associated to the selected category I perform a query to a SQLite database.

If category selected is valid, I want to call another activity to show a list of products for the category selected.

My problem in this scenario is how to stay in CategoryActivity until a valid category is selected taking into account that I do not want to implement the logic of query database within CategoryActivity.

For example, from MainActivity I call CategoryActivity. CategoryActivity returns the selected category identifier to MainActivity within onActivityResult. Within onActivityResult I receive the category identifier and I query the database to see if there are products for the selected category. If any, no problem, I call another activity to show the list of products belonging to the category selected but... if no products for the category selected... here is the problem.... how to call again the CategoryActivity... think that this process can be repeated more than one time until a valid category is selected...

A solution woluld be to implement the logic of checking if exist products for that category in the CategoryActivity and then if products exist call the another activity to list the products but I think this solution is not enough elegant as this code will be use only in scenario 2 but not necessary in scenario 1. Using this solution, CategoryActivity will behave different depending on the caller (for example by passing an enumeration to the intent that will define the behaviour of the activity)... is it an elegant way? For this reason I want to do this logic (to check product existence for the category) from outside CategoryActivity. Doing so, CategoryActivity always behaves the same way, that is, only returns the category selected, no matter if products exist for the category selected as this logic will be checked outside CategoryActivity. But doing so, there is no manner to stay CategoryActivity until a valid category is selected.

Antoher solution would be to create a new Activity-class with the same layout but other functionality but doing so I am repeating code... maybe more readable but less maintainable....

So how to get rid of this?

Comment: Can you include a picture?

Comment: Why don't you replace all your `Activities` (except for the `MainActivity`) with `Fragments` and then create a callback, so when the user selects a category, the `Fragment` will call back to the `MainActivity` and get it check if this category is valid? You probably won't get around having a "general" category class that will behave differently depending on the caller, but if you use `Fragments` you can make it more "light-weight"...